# How do I continue working on an existing django project in pycharm from ddesktop computer to my laptop?

Tags: django, pycharm, project

I created a django project in pycharm from my desktop computer. Now that I want to work on that same project from my laptop I'm not able to do so. What are the commands to be written in the terminal for continuing the project in pycharm from my laptop? (how do I work in that existing virtual environment and run the server now?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on a same project in multi device, the best option in using git which is distributed version-control system for tracking changes in source code during software development, for more information use the link below:
[git](https://git-scm.com/)

if you want to run your project on a virtual server, you have multi option, which on of them is using pycharm, pycharm has builtin tools for run your project, the other option is using builtin django and python virtual server that could run with this command : `python manage.py runserver`. for complete information about how run django project virtually, use this link:

[The development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server)

[Configure PyCharm for Python/Django](https://medium.com/@srijan.pydev_21998/configure-pycharm-for-python-django-and-introduction-to-django-rest-framework-f9c1a7cb4ba0)